# Firebase Realtime Database Query is not working with larger number

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am making query for my orders list, here is the data structure and my database rules:
[image]

[image]

I use a query like this to find out whether the latest price hit the tp or sl price like this:

```
function GetBuyList(symbol, currentPrice) {
    //Less than or equal to, for buying search tp lesser than current price
    var buy_tp = db.ref(`orders/active_orders/${symbol}`).orderByChild("tp").startAt(`buy_tp_${0}`).endAt(`buy_tp_${currentPrice}`)

    //More than or equal to, for buying search sl higher than current price
    var buy_sl = db.ref(`orders/active_orders/${symbol}`).orderByChild("sl").startAt(`buy_sl_${currentPrice}`).endAt(`buy_sl_${100000000}`)

    buy_tp.once("value", function (snapshot) {
        // do some stuff once
        if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
            ProcessOrders(snapshot.val(), 'tpHit', currentPrice)
        }
    });

    buy_sl.once("value", function (snapshot) {
        // do some stuff once
        if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
            ProcessOrders(snapshot.val(), 'slHit', currentPrice)
        }
    });
}
```

For price that is in lower value like 1.211, it working fine, but when the price goes larger, the buy_sl query is not working, but the buy_tp query is still working fine. Example, when I query for the price like 34886 for the data below the buy_sl is not working:

[image]

Edit:
Hi Frank, herein the json exported:

```
{
  "active_orders" : {
    "BTCUSD" : {
      "-Masii03kq9LvuLfWOyG" : {
        "close_type" : "None",
        "lot_size" : 1,
        "order_price" : 34888.17,
        "sl" : "buy_sl_34887",
        "symbol" : "BTCUSD",
        "tp" : "buy_tp_34889",
        "ts" : 1622301925456,
        "type" : "buy",
        "uid" : "6XaKYgXCsuMNg1d5bWYHg6ej5sd2"
      }
    },
    "EURUSD" : {
      "-MasVPCtD4sdPCcdF9S9" : {
        "close_type" : "None",
        "lot_size" : 1,
        "order_price" : 1.211,
        "sl" : "buy_sl_1.210",
        "symbol" : "EURUSD",
        "tp" : "buy_tp_1.23",
        "ts" : 1622298174339,
        "type" : "buy",
        "uid" : "6XaKYgXCsuMNg1d5bWYHg6ej5sd2"
      }
    },
    "USDJPY" : {
      "-MasWoRREHQhvOR6iQ8G" : {
        "close_type" : "None",
        "lot_size" : 1,
        "order_price" : 109.861,
        "sl" : "buy_sl_107.0",
        "symbol" : "USDJPY",
        "tp" : "buy_tp_110",
        "ts" : 1622298543910,
        "type" : "buy",
        "uid" : "6XaKYgXCsuMNg1d5bWYHg6ej5sd2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example, when I perform the function GetBuyList("EURUSD", 1.3) or GetBuyList("EURUSD", 1.1), the result returned as:

```
{
  '-MasVPCtD4sdPCcdF9S9': {
    close_type: 'None',
    lot_size: 1,
    order_price: 1.211,
    sl: 'buy_sl_1.210',
    symbol: 'EURUSD',
    tp: 'buy_tp_1.23',
    ts: 1622298174339,
    type: 'buy',
    uid: '6XaKYgXCsuMNg1d5bWYHg6ej5sd2'
  }
}
```

When I perform the function like this, GetBuyList("BTCUSD", 34890), it would return:

```
{
  '-Masii03kq9LvuLfWOyG': {
    close_type: 'None',
    lot_size: 1,
    order_price: 34888.17,
    sl: 'buy_sl_34887',
    symbol: 'BTCUSD',
    tp: 'buy_tp_34889',
    ts: 1622301925456,
    type: 'buy',
    uid: '6XaKYgXCsuMNg1d5bWYHg6ej5sd2'
  }
}
```

But when I run this, GetBuyList("BTCUSD", 34886), nothing is return.

Comment: 1) Can you show with a hardcoded value a query that doesn't return the results you expect. 2) Can you show the JSON that you expected returned from that query as text, instead of a screenshot? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Frank, thanks for the prompt reply, I had edit the post for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sl` and `tp` are both strings and because they are, they won't be parsed as numbers and instead are subject to lexiographic sorting.

One of the most common examples of this happening is if you look at a file list in a folder:

```
0.jpg
1.jpg
10.jpg
11.jpg
12.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
6.jpg
7.jpg
8.jpg
9.jpg
```

If you can't switch from using strings, you need to pad the number with your expected maximum number:

```
000.jpg
001.jpg
002.jpg
003.jpg
004.jpg
005.jpg
006.jpg
007.jpg
008.jpg
009.jpg
010.jpg
011.jpg
012.jpg
```

```js
const formatWithPadding = (inp, digits) => {
  let n = Number(inp), nStr = `${Math.abs(n)}`, sign = n<0;
  return (sign ? '+' : '-') + (
    nStr.length > digits
      ? nStr
      : `${"0".repeat((digits || 1) - 1)}${nStr}`.slice(-digits)
  )
};

const tpVal = 1.210;
const [integerPart, fractionalPart] = String(tpVal).split(".");
const tp = `buy_tp_${formatWithPadding(integerPart, 6)}.${fractionalPart || 0}`;

// tp is "buy_tp_+000001.210"
```

Comment: Thanks Sam! My problem solved after changed my query endAt parameter from `buy_sl_${100000000}` to `buy_sl_${999999999}`, its due to the lexiographic sorting. Appreciated!!

Comment: Btw, I should really pad the number instead just change the endAt value, because it treat 2 is larger than 10. Thanks again!